# How do I add a dynamic number of white spaces to the beginning of each row of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would I pad each row of the df to the left with enough spaces to ensure the row totals 30 characters?

I tried going down this path, but it didn't work and I believe `ljust` is deprecated:

```
'{: <30}'.format(df['test1'])
```

Currently:

```
>>> df['test1']
0    1234jjjjjjjdddd
1    1234jjjjjjjdd
2    1234jjjjjjjddddddddd
3    1234jjjjjjjddd
4    1234jjjjjjjdddddd
```

What I'm looking for:

```
>>> df['test1']
0                   1234jjjjjjjdddd
1                     1234jjjjjjjdd
2              1234jjjjjjjddddddddd
3                    1234jjjjjjjddd
4                 1234jjjjjjjdddddd
```

**Final Solution:**

```
df['test1'] = df.test1.str.rjust(30,' ')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.rjust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html):

```
print (df.test1.str.rjust(30, ' '))
0                   1234jjjjjjjdddd
1                     1234jjjjjjjdd
2              1234jjjjjjjddddddddd
3                    1234jjjjjjjddd
4                 1234jjjjjjjdddddd
Name: test1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect!  This is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
spaces = " " * 30
df['test1'] = [spaces[-len(i):] + i for i in df['test1']]
```